# How can I link a class to an enum?

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>

enum class Hobbit {
    // typedef HobbitHelper helper;
    UNKNOWN = -1, Bilbo, Frodo, Samwise
};

struct HobbitHelper {
    static Hobbit decode(std::string const& s) {
        if (s == "Bilbo") {
            return Hobbit::Bilbo;
        }
        else if (s == "Frodo") {
            return Hobbit::Frodo;
        }
        else if (s == "Samwise") {
            return Hobbit::Samwise;
        }
        else {
            return Hobbit::UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
};

enum class Wizard {
    // typedef Apprentice helper;
    UNKNOWN = -1, Gandalf, Radagast, Saruman
};

struct Apprentice { // WizardHelper :)
    static Wizard decode(std::string const& s) {
        if (s == "Gandalf") {
            return Wizard::Gandalf;
        }
        else if (s == "Radagast") {
            return Wizard::Radagast;
        }
        else if (s == "Saruman") {
            return Wizard::Saruman;
        }
        else {
            return Wizard::UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
T
decoder(std::string s)
{
    return ??::decode(s);
    // if the typedefs were allowed, I could use T::helper::decode()
}

int main()
{
    std::string s{ "Rincewind" };

    auto h = decoder<Hobbit>(s);
    auto w = decoder<Wizard>(s);
}
```

How can I arrange to call the appropriate helper class (HobbitHelper or Apprentice) in `decoder`? I can't declare a nested type inside the enum, as if it was a class. I also tried deriving the helper from the enum (since the helper itself has no data), but that isn't allowed either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just have the `helper` type trait be external and templated on the enum type, with an explicit specialization for each `enum`:

```
template <typename T> struct type_is { using type = T; };

template <typename > struct helper;

template <> struct helper<Hobbit> : type_is<HobbitHelper> { };
template <> struct helper<Wizard> : type_is<Apprentice> { };

template <typename T>
using helper_t = typename helper<T>::type;
```

And then `decode` would just access that:

```
template <typename T>
T decoder(std::string s)
{
    return helper_t<T>::decode(s);
}
```

Comment: while I have grown to dislike the word helper, that is a pretty elegant answer (upvoted).

Comment: This solution is also distributable: the `template <> struct helper<Hobbit> : type_is<HobbitHelper> { };` specializations can each be in the appropriate header. Renaming `helper_t` to `helper_of` makes it even more mnemonic.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be partial template specialization, although the answer from @Barry might be more like what you are looking for.

```
template <typename T>
T decoder(std::string s);

template<>
Hobbit decoder(std::string s)
{
    return HobbitHelper::decode(s);
}

template<>
Wizard decoder(std::string s)
{
    return Apprentice::decode(s);
}
```

Comment: Uh. I was certain you had forgotten the arguments in the specialization, but it compiles without them indeed... Sorry for that ! Edit : well I indeed learnt something here. Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is to use ADL. You can use a type tag to make the compiler look in the appropriate namespace.

Consider:

```
template<typename T> struct adl_tag {};
namespace MiddleEarth {
    enum class Hobbit {
        // typedef HobbitHelper helper;
        UNKNOWN = -1, Bilbo, Frodo, Samwise
    };
    Hobbit decode(std::string const& s, adl_tag<Hobbit>) {
        if (s == "Bilbo") {
            return Hobbit::Bilbo;
        }
        else if (s == "Frodo") {
            return Hobbit::Frodo;
        }
        else if (s == "Samwise") {
            return Hobbit::Samwise;
        }
        else {
            return Hobbit::UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
}
template<typename T> T decode(std::string s) {
    return decode(s, adl_tag<T>());
}
```

This is the solution employed by pretty much all C++ libraries- more or less. There's basically no additional effort involved. I didn't even have to *mention* Wizard.

Comment: Both Hobbit and Wizard are in the `MiddleEarth` namespace :)

Comment: I can't see this working if `Hobbit decode(......)` is not a free function, but a static member of e.g. `HobbitHelper` (like in the original question).

Comment: @Bulletmagnet: Putting such functions as static members of classes is bad practice in C++, it's a pointless Javaism and locks down many of the languages more useful features- such as ADL. If you put functions like that in a class, you have bigger problems than a little messy calling syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Aside helper problem there is better solution than cascade `if`:

```
static Hobbit decode(std::string const& s) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::strinng,Hobbit> choice {
        { "Bilbo", Hobbit::Bilbo },
        { "Frodo", Hobbit::Frodo },
        { "Samwise", Hobbit::Samwise }
    };
    auto f = choice.find( s );
    return f != choice.end() ? f->second : Hobbit::UNKNOWN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with a slightly modified version of [Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32012646/2064196)

```
template <typename T>
struct enumclass {
};

template<>
struct enumclass<Hobbit> {
    using helper = HobbitHelper;
};

template<>
struct enumclass<Wizard> {
    using helper = Apprentice;
};
```

because it lets me write the more mnemonic

```
template <typename T>
T
decoder(std::string s)
{
    return enumclass<T>::helper::decode(s);
}
```

All the specializations can be distributed (i.e. `enumclass <Hobbit>` is in `hobbit.h`; `enumclass<Wizard>` is in `wizard.h`). All these headers must include a small header with the unspecialized template.